# What's this 'yes n' doing in this make file

Tags: shell, makefile

[image]

I came across this piece from https://github.com/abo-abo/oremacs.git, and get confused about the usage of yes n| cp -i ... Appreciate if there's any explanation.

Comment: Try typing "man yes" at your command prompt.

Comment: 'yes n' will display 'n' forever in the prompt, so... what? why this is needed? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: It won't display it in the prompt, it will echo it *to the command it's piped into*. Basically, it will answer no to any question the command asks.

Answer (score 3):

The `yes` command outputs the same string - by default, the letter y - over and over again, separated by line breaks. When run on its own, this is pretty pointless, but thanks to the way Unix pipes work, it's a simple way of making interactive programs non-interactive.

When a program asks you to press y or n to confirm something, it normally reads the answer from its standard input stream; by piping the output of `yes` to the program, it will act as though there was someone hammering y return y return y return endlessly - so every question is answered "yes".

In this case, `yes n` means to output n instead of y, so every question is answered "no". This is then used with `cp -i`, which will ask for conformation if a file is about to be overwritten. So the makefile is copying files into place *only if there is no file already at the target location*.

Answer (score 0):

basically it pipes the n (edited) char to the following command and since they use interactive cp if there is any issue it will accept y as the answer.

Comment: Actually it outputs 'n' in this case, because that's the argument they gave it.

Comment: sorry haven't noticed. Thanks